# Ruby: script to convert structured text to a csv

Tags: ruby, csv, text

I have a text file with structured text which I wish to convert to a csv file.

The file looks something like:

```
name: Seamus
address: 123 Strand Avenue

name: Seana
address: 126 Strand Avenue
```

I would like it to look like:

```
|name    | address
______________________________
|Seamus  | 123 Strand Avenue
______________________________
|Seana   | 126 Strand Avenue
```

So I understand that I need to do something like;

1. create a csv file
2. create the column names
3. read the text file
4. for each row of the text file starting with 'name' I assign the following text to the 'name' column, for ech row starting with 'address' assign the value to the 'address' column etc.

But I dont' know how to do so.

I would appreciate any pointers people could provide.

Comment: You've done a good job of defining your problem. However, your question is too broad to be a good fit for StackOverflow's format. You'll have much more luck here if you pick a specific part of your problem, attempt to solve it on your own, and then, if you get stuck, come back and posing a more focused question that includes the code you've written so far. In this case I'd start with reading the text file, as there are [lots of existing resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+a+text+file+in+ruby&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2016%2Ccd_max%3A&tbm=) to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution starts by identifying how to parse the text file. In this specific case what separates the "records" in the text file is an empty line.

First step would be importing the file contents:

```
string_content = File.read("path/to/my_file.txt")
# => "name: Seamus\naddress: 123 Strand Avenue\n\nname: Seana\naddress: 126 Strand Avenue\n"
```

Then you would need to separate the records. As you can see when parsing the file the empty line is a line that only contains `\n`, so the `\n` from the line above plus the one on the empty line make `\n\n`. That is what you need to look for to separate the records:

```
string_records = string_content.split("\n\n")
# => ["name: Seamus\naddress: 123 Strand Avenue", "name: Seana\naddress: 126 Strand Avenue\n"]
```

And then once you have the strings with the records is just a matter of splitting by `\n` again to separate the fields:

```
records_by_field = string_records.map do |string_record|
  string_record.split("\n")
end
# => [["name: Seamus", "address: 123 Strand Avenue"], ["name: Seana", "address: 126 Strand Avenue"]]
```

Once that is separated you need to split the records by `:` to separate field_name and value:

```
data = records_by_field.map do |record|
  record.each_with_object({}) do |field, new_record|
    field_name, field_value = field.split(":")
    new_record[field_name] = field_value.strip # don't forget to get rid of the initial space with String#strip
  end
end
# => [{"name"=>"Seamus", "address"=>"123 Strand Avenue"}, {"name"=>"Seana", "address"=>"126 Strand Avenue"}]
```

And there you have it! An array of hashes with the correct key-value pairs.

Now from that you can create a CSV or just use it to give it any other format you may want.

To resolve your specific CSV question:

```rb
require 'csv'

# first you need to get your column headers, which will be the keys of any of the hashes, the first will do
column_names = data.first.keys

CSV.open("output_file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  # first we add the headers
  csv << column_names

  # for each data row we create an array with values ordered as the column_names
  data.each do |data_hash|
    csv << [data_hash[column_names[0]], data_hash[column_names[1]]]
  end
end
```

That will create an `output_file.csv` in the same directory where you run your ruby script.

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's construct the file.

```
str =<<~END
name: Seamus
address: 123 Strand Avenue

name: Seana
address: 126 Strand Avenue


address: 221B Baker Street
name: Sherlock
END
```

Notice that I've added a third record that has the order of the "name" and "address" lines reversed, and it is preceded by an extra blank line.

```
in_file = 'temp.txt'
File.write(in_file, str)
  #=> 124
```

The first step is to to obtain the headers for the CSV file:

```
headers = []
f = File.open(in_file)
loop do
  header = f.gets[/[^:]+(?=:)/]
  break if header.nil?
  headers << header
end
f.close
```

```
headers
  #=> ["name", "address"]
```

Notice that the number of headers (two in the example) is arbitrary.

See [IO::gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-i-gets). The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters other than a colon" immediately followed by a colon (`(?=:)` being a *positive lookahead*).

If `in_file` is not exceedingly large it's easiest to first read that file into an array of hashes. The first step is to read the file into a string and then split the string on contiguous lines that contain nothing other than newlines and spaces:

```
arr = File.read(in_file).chomp.split(/\n\s*\n/)
  #=> ["name: Seamus\naddress: 123 Strand Avenue",
  #    "name: Seana\naddress: 126 Strand Avenue",
  #    "address: 221B Baker Street\nname: Sherlock"]
```

We can now convert each element of this array to a hash:

```
arr = File.read(in_file).split(/\n\s*\n/).
           map do |s|
             s.split("\n").
               each_with_object({}) do |p,h| 
                 key, value = p.split(/: +/)
                 h[key] = value
               end
           end
  #=> [{"name"=>"Seamus", "address"=>"123 Strand Avenue"},
  #    {"name"=>"Seana", "address"=>"126 Strand Avenue"},
  #    {"address"=>"221B Baker Street", "name"=>"Sherlock"}]
```

We are now ready to construct the CSV file:

```
out_file = 'temp.csv'
```

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open(out_file, 'w') do |csv|
  csv << headers
  arr.each { |h| csv << h.values_at(*headers) }
end
```

Let's see what was written:

```
puts File.read(out_file)
name,address
Seamus,123 Strand Avenue
Seana,126 Strand Avenue
Sherlock,221B Baker Street
```

See [CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) and [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

This is not the format specified in the question. In fact, a file with that format would not be a valid CSV file, because there is no consistent column separator. For example, the first line, `'|name    | address'` has a column separator `'    | '`, whereas the second line, `'|Seamus  | 123 Strand Avenue'` has a column separator `'  | '`. Moreover, even if they were the same the pipe at the beginning of each line would become the first letter of the name.

We could change the column separator to a pipe (rather than a comma, the default) by writing `CSV.open(out_file, col_sep: '|', 'w')`. A common mistake in constructing CSV files is to surround the column separator with one or more spaces. That invariably leads to boo-boos.